# RuntimeError: Unable to load symbol [JNI_CreateJavaVM], error = dlsym(0x201b1d2c0, JNI_CreateJavaVM): symbol not found

Tags: java, pynetlogo

Hi I am trying to a run a library called `pyNetlogo` in m1 mac. However when I run `NetLogoLink` function I get the following error.

```
netlogo = pyNetLogo.NetLogoLink(
    gui = False,
    netlogo_home = "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.3"
)
```

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] JVM DLL not found: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libjli.dylib`

Since it seemed that JVM could not be found by the function I gave the path explicitly

```
netlogo = pyNetLogo.NetLogoLink(
    gui = False,
    netlogo_home = "/Applications/NetLogo 6.0.3",
    jvm_home = "/usr/bin/java"
)
```

However notw I get the following error and I am not too sure how to solve it.
`RuntimeError: Unable to load symbol [JNI_CreateJavaVM], error = dlsym(0x201b1d2c0, JNI_CreateJavaVM): symbol not found`

Any Idea how to fix it?